# How to remove OpenIDs from my account and use regular logins?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

For some reasons irrelevant to the question, I would like to stop using OpenID providers to log in to the SE network.

In My Profile -> My Logins, I can add another OpenID login. But I would like to not use OpenIDs to log in. I want to log in using a username/email + password. Is this possible?

Comment: I only have one login provider attached to my account (SE openID), but when I go to settings -> my logins, a remove button appears to the far right of the OpenID provider name. Can you see that?

Comment: @angussidney I never know that SE OpenIDs existed. It would have been more intuitive if a link to signup/login using SE OpenID is there in the "Add Logins" page. Can I now change this to a feature request?

Comment: The regular email/password *is* an OpenID, just SE's own OpenID https://openid.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See dupe's top answer: "This gets a bit more complicated when you're trying to add a Stack Exchange OpenID, particularly if you're already using a different SE OpenID..."